# Angular Karma not running all unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wrote two unittests but there are not executed.
Please see the two screen shots below.

What is wrong, why it is not executed?

As you can read I get the message:
    *"executed **45 of 47**"*
Means also, the test are found, just not executed.
How can it be?

Frank

[image: @Terminal]

[image: @Karma]

```html
describe('LanguageSelectorComponent', () => {
  let component: LanguageSelectorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LanguageSelectorComponent>;
  let find: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LanguageSelectorComponent],
      imports: [DxModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler, NGXLogger, LanguageSelectorService]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.overrideComponent(LanguageSelectorComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [{ provide: LanguageSelectorService, useClass: MockLanguageSelectorService }]
      }
    }).createComponent(LanguageSelectorComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    find = (de => selector => de.query(By.css(selector)))(fixture.debugElement);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should create dx select box', () => {
    expect(find('dx-select-box')).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you post the other specs! I guess they might be prefixed with `f`

Comment: You might have accedently put `xdescribe` or `xit` in those two test files.

Answer (score 2):

You can run only few test cases as you wish using karma-jasmine. This is possible either by prefixing `describe` with f (stands for focus) as `fdescribe` or `it` as `fit`.

`fdescribe` runs all the test specs implemented within that component. `fit` runs only that particular test spec. It is possible to do `fit` on multiple test specs which will run multiple test scpes ignoring the others.

To exclude few test specs or the entire component use `xit` or `xdescribe` respectively.

Please look at your specs for these special key words. Your problem might get solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to find in my code above. 
My languageSelectorService was including a cookieStoreService
and there was a mismatch while building the app.
I moved the cookieStoreService into the component and now it works.

Thanks to Amit for your lines!
(I learned about fdescribe.)

Frank